# Create new column week in no time series dataset

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to create a time structure on my dataframe.

I've got a dataframe with a column called 'day', df['day'] spans from 1 to 365 with missing numbers, it looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,8,8,9,9,10,11,11,12,13]})
```

I'd like to create a new column 'weekOftheYear' such that every 5 days it displays the week. The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
day  week
1     1
2     1
2     1
2     1
3     1  
...   ...
8     2
8     2
9     2
...   ...
```

---

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Comment: What's your attempt?

Comment: I'm trying to generate the week of the year with respect of the day of the year.there aren't weekends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
df['week'] = (df['day'] + 2) // 7 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why would you display what you want to be displayed every 5 days, but I believe this solution will work for you.

```
df['week'] = df['day'].apply(lambda x: x//7+1)
```

Edit after OPs comment.

If for 1-4 you want to get 1 and for 5-11 2 and so on then you just need to move all your days by `n`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1,1,2,2,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,9]})
df['fixed_days'] = df['day'] + 2
df['week'] = df['fixed_days'].apply(lambda x: x//7+1)
df.drop('fixed_days', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Prints

```
    day week
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   2   1
4   5   2
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work in my case because my 'day' column starts with 1 = Thursday, 2 = Friday then 3 and 4 are missing and 5= Monday. The minal working example should be: df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1,1,2,2,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,9,9]})

Comment: @MoorZ I believe it works now. Please mark it solved if this solution suits you.

Comment: @TomWojcik - Yes, it working, sorry! But better is not use `apply` ;)